# MultiView Android Delphi with TWebBrowser

Tags: android, delphi, multiview, overriding

Using the MultiView component in an area containing TWebBrowser, the component overrides the MultiView . Is there a way to fix this?

Usage: Delphi XE8 Update 1

**There is no code in this first test. All configuration is visual with MultiView**

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: All configuration is visual with MultiView

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use TWebBrowser.MakeScreenshot and hide TWebBrowser when the TMultiView opens up. Fill a TImage or a TRectangle.Fill where the hidden TWebBrowser is with the screenshot.

Comment: The componente TBannerAd not working MakeScreenshot.the temporary solution I found was to put a black rectangle instead of the banner when multiview is open