# Why Multiview always behind TWebBrowser?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Using Delphi Tokyo I opened the sample firemonkey project about multiview and I put TWebBrowser. My problem when the multiview in drawer mode is open the TWebBrowser is always on top !! how to fix that ?

I read this solution but I really hope there is better solution in Tokyo

[MultiView Android Delphi with TWebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757559/multiview-android-delphi-with-twebbrowser)

[image]

The white area is the twebbrowser above the multiview.

Comment: Well, have you hide the web browser control as the answer in your linked post suggests, then?

Comment: `WebBrowser1.Visible := false;` does not work after pressing on the master button

Comment: I see, so you think the answer is outdated (which might be, as FMX is a moving target). To be honest, I've almost no experience here, just what is your setting of the [Drawer Mode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_a_MultiView_Component_to_Display_Alternate_Views_of_Information_(iOS_and_Android)#Drawer_Mode)? And, can we reproduce this on Windows platform in Tokyo (or it happens just on specific platforms)?

Comment: @Victoria no other settings I tried all modes like platformbehavior . you can test the behavior in widows except for popover it appear normally in windows but in Android it does not appear at all. and yes the answer in another post wont work with me.

Comment: The web browser control is a horrible mess in Firemonkey last I tried it. I even put it on a panel, and made that panel hidden, and STILL the web browser showed through. I abandoned the whole idea of using a web browser in FMX and went back to VCL because of that.

Comment: @JerryDodge can we post this problem to embarcadero ?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if someone already did. I never checked. But I do recall that control defies all rules of typical control behavior in Delphi, including issues with simply positioning it.

Comment: Can we get a *.fmx (form settings code) source, please? I would like to try to reproduce this.

Comment: @Victoria open this sample `Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\User Interface\MultiView` put Twebbrwoser, set align as a client in a panel and test it on windows. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't installed samples; [this one](https://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Object%20Pascal/Mobile%20Samples/User%20Interface/MultiView/) you meant? I'll try to investigate :-)

Comment: @Victoria yes this is the one.

Comment: Well, that sample uses [CustomPresentationClass](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.MultiView.TCustomMultiView.CustomPresentationClass). And I believe there is a solution even when not using custom presentation class, just cannot say that for sure (at least I cannot test that on Android).

Comment: @Victoria np let me know your idea.

Comment: Idea, erm, that sample manipulates with the view placement quite much. I would try to search for some simple example (which shows just how to create a detail view).